# Python Requests Google Custom Site Search Without API

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm trying to create a webscraper which will get links from Google search result page. Everything works fine, but I want to search a specific site only, i.e., instead of `test`, I want to search for `site:example.com test`. The following is my current code:

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

s_term=input("Enter search term: ").replace(" ","+")
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search', params={'q':'"'+s_term+'"','num':"50","tbs":"li:1"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    links.append(item.a['href'])

print(links)
```

I tried using: `...params={'q':'"site%3Aexample.com+'+s_term+'"'...` but it returns 0 results.

Comment: `r.status_code` == 503? Goodle doesn't like bots or google dorks..

Comment: No, its returning 200. But it displays, `Your search - <b>"site%3Atwitter.com+Manikiran"</b> - did not match any documents.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your existing params to the below one:

```
params={"source":"hp","q":"site:example.com test","oq":"site:example.com test","gs_l":"psy-ab.12...10773.10773.0.22438.3.2.0.0.0.0.135.221.1j1.2.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..1.1.135.6..35i39k1.zWoG6dpBC3U"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need `"q"` params. Also, make sure you're using `user-agent` because Google might block your requests eventually thus you'll receive a completely different HTML. I already answered [what is `user-agent` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979968/15164646).

Pass `params`:

```py
params = {
  "q": "site:example.com test"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get(YOUR_URL, headers=headers)
```

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "site:example.com test"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link)

# http://example.com/
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out how to make stuff work since it's already done for the end-user and the only thing that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "site:example.com test",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])

# http://example.com/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.